# ASP.NET :- MSUnit testing Multiple test cases

Tags: asp.net-mvc, unit-testing, asp.net-core

I wanted to run multiple test cases for one function by passing parameters.

This is the function for add two numbers.

```
[DataTestMethod]
        [DataRow()]
        public void addMethodTest(int a,int b,int result)
        {
            //Arrange
            DemoController demoController = new DemoController();

            //Act
             int TestResult = demoController.add(a, b);

            //Assert
            Assert.Equals(result,TestResult);
        }
```

How should I pass parameters to above function?

Answer (score 0):

You can use multiple [DataRow()] attributes with corresponding parameters inside i.e.

```
    [TestMethod]
    [DataRow("some string")]
    [DataRow("some other string")]
    public void InputStrings_ShouldTransformCorrectly(string input)
    {
        var result = this.stringTransformationService.Transform(input);

        Assert.IsTrue(result);
        Assert.IsNotNull(input);
    }
```

For more information on DataRowAttribute, you can check the [Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.visualstudio.testtools.unittesting.datarowattribute?view=mstest-net-1.2.0)